# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected in POST Request in Java

Tags: java, post

Here is what i am doing. After setdoOutput(true), exception is throwing. Not able to understand why.

```
        URL url = new URL(subscriberUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        //After above line exception is thrown
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(bytedata, 0, bytedata.length);
        os.flush();

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
        }
        conn.disconnect();
```

Comment: May be the subscriber  expects some specific input type or some header which you are not sending.

Comment: openConnection() doesn't actually connect to the URL before getOuputStream is called so I don't think you get this error. Are you sure?

Comment: try to set `con.setRequestMethod("POST");` before `conn.setDoOutput(true);`.